# Android Java: Filter a list with elements in another list using Stream API

Tags: android, list, filter, stream, java-stream

I cannot paste much code because I'm not sure about how to achieve my goal, and every code I write with Stream ends underlined in red.

I know how to filter a list based on a property like:

```
List<RecordDTO> filteredRecords = Stream.of(records).filter(item -> item.getIdTest().equals(test.getIdTest())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but don't know how to do it based on another list.

My app works with tests and records, and I have a List<Test> testsList where every test has an id, and a List<Record> recordsList where every record has an idTest.

From the full list of records, I need to get the ones containing an idTest belonging to the testsList, but not sure how to do it with Stream.

I'm just trying to avoid the use of for loops and use smarter code, that's why I'm trying to do the filtering with Stream.

Any example?

Comment: Maybe you can add the code of `Test` and `Record` classes to your question, so that the relationship between them will be more clear.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Alexander Ivanchenko. I can do that when I'm out of the office, but I can tell you in advance that I'm using a non relational database, and the only relationship is that I store records ov every test taken, so the "relation" is that records have a TestId property that relates that specific record with a test.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I found a solution by myself. Hope it is useful to anyone else.

```
List<String> testsIds = Stream.of(tests4Subject).map(TestDTO::getIdTest).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<RecordDTO> filteredRecords = New ArrayList();
if(testsIds!=null)
{
   filteredRecords = Stream.of(records).filter(p -> testsIds.contains(p.getIdTest())).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: **1.** `testsIds` will never be `null`. **2.** The scope of `filteredRecords` is limited to the block of curly braces after the `if` statement.

Comment: Yes, this is because it is just an example on how to do it, I have to make final adjustments @Alexander Ivanchenko.